# Getting Error While creating new database : odoo

Tags: database, odoo-17

'''
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\http.py", line 2150, in **call**
response = request._serve_db()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\http.py", line 1701, in _serve_db
self.registry = Registry(self.db).check_signaling()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 89, in **new**
return cls.new(db_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 2, in new
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 113, in new
odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 502, in load_modules
registry.setup_models(cr)
File "", line 2, in setup_models
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 306, in setup_models
env['ir.model']._add_manual_models()
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 468, in _add_manual_models
cr.execute("SELECT *, name->>'en_US' AS name FROM ir_model WHERE state = 'manual'")
File "C:\Users\nisar\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoo_erp\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 332, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "ir_model" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT *, name->>'en_US' AS name FROM ir_model WHERE state =...
'''

this error is throwing only when i try to create new db but existing db's are working fine.